# Failure to book reported by OTA, but a refusal to refund. What to do?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, refunds

I have flown from Berlin TXL to Paris ORY with Aigle Azur, flight number ZI608 (09:55 --- 11:55) on the 30th of April 2019. There is a circumstance regarding ticket sale which has had me, so far unsuccessfully, attempt to obtain a refund for the flight.

I have purchased a ticket through MyHolidays, an intermediary. I have received a confirmation of the booking soon afterwards. Simultaneously, I have received the following email:

> From: "Please do not respond"
>
> RECLOC = [redacted] (same one as in the email)
>
> Gentile Cliente
>   Siamo spiacenti ma, a causa di una problema, il biglietto non e stato emesso.Per informazioni vi preghiamo contattare il Ticketing Travel Center al
>   numero 025275407 ext 2 Agenzie di Viaggio dal lunedi' al venerdi' dalle ore 09.00 alle ore 13.00 e dalle 14.00 alle 19.00,
>   sabato dalle 09.30 alle 12.30

Google Translation:

> Dear Customer
>
> We are sorry but due to a problem the ticket has not been issued. For information please contact the Ticketing Travel Center at
>   number 025275407 ext 2 Travel Agencies from Monday to Friday from 09.00 to 13.00 and from 14.00 to 19.00,
>   Saturday from 09.30 to 12.30

In order to confirm what the email claimed, I accessed Aigle Azur's website and entered the flight details into the check-in form. The website promptly informed me that a booking with the provided booking number could not be found.

Basing my judgment on the aforementioned clues, as well as under pressure to secure a seat on a flight departing in three days, I opted to book another ticket, this time directly with Aigle Azur.

I have been in touch with MyHolidays customer service, which denies me a refund, saying that the first ticket remained valid. They refuse to consider the email that I have received.

I have ultimately checked in and flown on the second ticket.

What would be the best course to contest the ticket and obtain a refund? I am quite unhappy about the unnecessary expense as well as the treatment.

Comment: If you paid MyHolidays with a credit card, Step One is contesting the charge. Did you talk to their Customer Service before getting the second ticket, and if so, what did they say?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I have only reached out to them after purchasing the second ticket. It was most likely a misjudgment. I suppose that I would not have purchased the second ticket, had I spoken to them. I acted on written communication instead.